# Geometric meaning of conductor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Supppose $L/K$ is a finite extension, choose $\theta \in O_L$ such that $L=K(\theta)$. We define the conductor of ring $O_K[\theta]$ to be an ideal of $O_L$, namely: $F=\{\alpha\in O_L|\alpha\cdot O_L\subseteq O_K[\theta]\}$.

For ring $k[T^2,T^3],k[T^2-1,T(T^2-1)]$, their conductors in $k[T]$ are some ideal supported at inverse image of singularities.

What is the geometric meaning of the ideal of a conductor for curves? How do we use conductors in algebraic number theory?

For any finite morphism of varieties, we can define the conductor in the same way, does it have a meaning?

Comment: You can find a relationship between the conductor ideal and the "adjoint ideal" in 9.3.51 of Lazarsfeld's _Positivity_.